# Is there any way we can control push operations in git branches?

Tags: gitlab

As maintainer, I want to temporarily block the git branch for push operation by all users having developer access.

Is there any way on GitLab that enables this feature?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you *want* to do this? That may help provide a better answer to achieve your underlying goal.

Comment: I would want some maintainer activities in that blocked time like rebasing with other branches and get the branch synced with my desired branches

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is possible with a Push Rule. in Settings > Repository for the repo, open the Protected Branches section, select your branch, and select "No one" for allowed to push.

Gitlab docs: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/protected_branches.html

Comment: This is also possible in any git remote (Gitlab or elsewhere) incidentally, using a git feature called pre-receive hooks- but gitlab has a convenient UI for this.

Comment: Apparently only maintainers can push into protected branch. Mine isn't protected branch, all users with developer access can push the code in my branch. Your answer does not work for non-protected branches

Comment: i think the best solution is the one described above. You can just use a wildcard in the form to control the access of all branches.

Comment: it seems like temporarily making it a protected branch is the way to go then

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me that your workflow is a bit odd.
If a branch is regularly protected temporarily from pushing, it should always be a protected branch where changes come in via merge requests.

When you want no changes to this branch, you just don't accept any merge request for the time being.

Reference: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/

Comment: Makes sense. I may have to look into other approaches to control my branch